# Cannot delete item from CosmosDB

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use an Azure Functions httpTrigger call to delete an item from my database.

```
import { CosmosClient,  } from '@azure/cosmos'

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    const client = new CosmosClient(process.env.cosmosDB)
    const database = client.database('testDB');
    const container = database.container('workers');
    const item = container.item('28a31558-ff8c-40c3-a7e8-1e8904c5ff72', '/id')
    console.log(await item.delete())
}
```

I even tried to hardcode the values into the code (as you can see) but I will always get 404 not found error:

```
Executed 'Functions.worker-delete' (Failed, Id=81ab43cf-a223-48af-89e1-a15676346ef0)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.worker-delete. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: Error: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system., 
RequestStartTime: 2020-05-11T12:30:44.4010890Z, RequestEndTime: 2020-05-11T12:30:44.4010890Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
ResponseTime: 2020-05-11T12:30:44.4010890Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: xxx, LSN: 769914, GlobalCommittedLsn: 769914, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 404, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#769914, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Delete
, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0
Stack: Error: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system., 
RequestStartTime: 2020-05-11T12:30:44.4010890Z, RequestEndTime: 2020-05-11T12:30:44.4010890Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
ResponseTime: 2020-05-11T12:30:44.4010890Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: xxx, LSN: 769914, GlobalCommittedLsn: 769914, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 404, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#769914, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Delete
, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0
    at xxx/node_modules/@azure/cosmos/dist/index.js:6973:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (xxx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:62)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7).
```

I tripple checked:

- connection string
- database name
- container name
- item-id
- partition

Comment: The 2nd parameter (partition key) in your call to `container.item()` should be the *value* of your partition key, not the *path* to the partition key.

Comment: holy cow, this is working - if you post it as an anwser, i will mark it "correct answer". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When retrieving a document via `container.item()`, the two parameters are:

- document id
- partition key

The 2nd parameter (partition key) needs to be the *value* of the partition key. In your example, you had the *path* to the partition key instead, so it's checking for a partition key value of "/id":

```
const item = container.item('28a31558-ff8c-40c3-a7e8-1e8904c5ff72', '/id')
```

This needs to be changed to:

```
const item = container.item('28a31558-ff8c-40c3-a7e8-1e8904c5ff72', '<partition-key-value')
```